# Archlinux ARM Rasperry Pi login buffer display and decryption fail

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, login, cryptsetup, mkinitcpio

I have put the Archlinux Arm on my SD card and the first time I have done this it was all correct and worked well but I had to "reinstall" everything for several reason. So now I am doing the same steps as before but I getting a weird "problems".
When I first started everything seems normal than I update the system and install "sudo mkinitcpio rsync". When I now reboot it and see the login screen it looks like this:

```
alarmpi login: [    14.9646851 smsc95xx 1-1.1:1 eth0 link up, 100Mbps, full-dupley, lpa 0x41E1
```

And I have to first press Enter to login and when I wait a bit some new lines appear they look like the following one:

```
[   602.262297] bcm2708_fb_blank blank_mode=1
```

I want to encrypt a part of my SD card and I have followed this https://gist.github.com/pezz/5310082 instructions which worked the first time just fine, as I am having a German keboard I need to use "keyboard keymap encrypt" in the mkinitcpio.conf file, but I have not able to decrypt it, it is always returned that there is no such key, although I am preatty sure I am doing the same steps as before when it has worked quite well and nicely.

So,
I have made a test, I have used the word "root" as my keyphase for my encryption. This works and I can boot but if I am using the following key:
"Xö&(4n=%YF3Ü!BN"
it does not work. Could anybody give me a hint why? Are there any characheters I am not allowed to use, although I am using the German keyboard layout de-latin1 an I do load keymap after keyboard, so the needed keyboardmaps should be loaded correctly, although it should have worked I have tested this with the keyphrase "y" which was on the right place as y and z poition are exchanged on US and Germany keyboard layouts. Also when I need to open the encrypted volume after I have created it the key works.

I am looking forward to hear from you. :-)

King regards,

Greeneco

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't be worry about `[   602.262297] bcm2708_fb_blank blank_mode=1` and similar messages, they are all kernel messages, which are written to console because logging daemon is not ready yet for writing them to a file. Just ignore it or put `loglevel=3` into kernel commandline options.

Second thing is with passing passphrase do decrypt luks master key. Try adding:

```
vconsole.keymap=de-latin1 vconsole.font=lat9w-16
```

to kernel commandlist. You should also add `keymap consolefont` to `HOOKS=` in `mkinitcpio.conf`.

That should do the thing and allow you to write German diacritic characters in passphrase.

HTH, Cheers.

Comment: thanks for your anwser, I was unable to comment and I am also unable to vote your question up. When you say the commandline options do you mean the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file if I am using Grub?

Comment: @user3852496 presumably, yes. However, those options should be changed by editing `/etc.default/grub` and then running `sudo grub-install`. Do not edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly.

Comment: Nope, nope @terdon... this is Arch Linux. After any changes to /etc/default/grub, you need to do only `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. No need to install grub again ;)

Comment: @ScylddeFraud sorry, I forgot this was arch. The `grub-install` script on Debian and RedHat based systems is a simple wrapper that runs `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it does not reinstall the grub package.

Comment: I always fought that it was `update-grub` and not the `grub-install` ;-)